# Should i create a constructor with a setter

Tags: java, oop

Every Time i create a new class i wonder what is the best way to create a constructor. If i use the default constructor made in IntelliJ it would create a constructor like example A. But at school we learn to use methode B.

Is there some big difference between A and B.

Is there some preferred way or is just a programmers choice ?

Example A:

```
public Model(int modelNumber) {
    this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
}
```

Example B

```
public Model(int modelNumber) {
    setModelNumber(modelNumber);

}

public void setModelNumber(int modelNumber) {
    this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
}
```

Comment: It depends upon whether you require mutable or immutable fields. Immutability has [some very attractive properties](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29), and is often recommended (e.g. in Effective Java), but it requires you to set all the values in the constructor.

Comment: In example B, you risk a subclass to override the method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless your class is marked as `final`, example B in its current form is definitely wrong.

The principle you need to follow is that **you mustn't call overrideable methods from your constructor**. If you don't obey that rule, you can't maintain class invariants: you can't guarantee that a subclass doesn't change what `setModelNumber()` does and you can end up with a `modelNumber` field that hasn't been initialised to the expected value.

*Failing to follow this principle could carry other, less obvious, but no less damaging [consequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) too.*

And for that reason it's usually preferable that you set the fields directly from the constructor. Not only that, in the case of `final` fields, that is your **only** option.

Answer (score 6):

Example A is more preferred, The moment you create your object you need to call the constructor to initialize values of your class members, setters and getters are used for other functions in your code to make use of the same members! It becomes extremely important to consider Example A. You can't do the calling setter if you want to inherit this class. You cannot make your class non inheritable.

So the answer is **NO!** Don't use Example B!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with the idea of

> you mustn't call overrideable methods from your constructor"

[as biziclop user said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34066768/2823516), so try to avoid the B example! 
In addition, B example is more expensive than the A. Think about the processor. Instead of going directly to the class attribute `modelNumber` it has to go to `setModelNumber` method first. Once there, it has to setup the `modelNumber` with the specified one. In the end, both examples do the same, but A is more direct and efficient.